# refresh a div with as if it was a page refresh

Tags: php, jquery, html

Is it possible to reload a `div` as if it was a page refresh?

I have an jQuery submit my from and return only the raw data arrays as intended. There is no html being returned just arrays of data.
How do I refresh the `div`'s html and php content, so it is populated with new data?

Here is what I've done so far to submit the form and return the data.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input:checkbox").change( function() {

var url = "index.php?action=resortFilter";

$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: url,
       data: $("#locationFilter").serialize(), 
       success: function(data)
       {
           $(".resorts").html(data);
       }
     });
   })
});
```

It returns all the correct data except currently it just overwrites the `div` that contains all my html and php to display the data. Because the return is only data it effectively empties the `div`

The html and php page is structured like so

```
<div class="resorts">
    <?php foreach ( $results['data'] as $data ) { ?>
        <table></table> and so on..................
</div>
```

Now I cannot alter the file that actually handles the form and put in the html and php to return it. So I need to find a means of using the code already in the page itself

Comment: it should refresh and repopulate with the new data not just empty itself

Comment: you have 2 options here : **1** to modify your current webservice that return array, to return desired html **2** to create a web service that returns html specific to 1 element from array, and make a ajax call to get the array and then for every element in array call service for that element, both methods have advantages and disatvanges, IMHO ill go with 2 method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two options either use ajax to call php that gets the array of data and returns it as html. Or you will have to use javascript to go through the array of data and convert it into usable html. You CANNOT get php code to run again on the client's computer, it is a server side language.

If you can't modify the code that the form is submitted to, can you create a new php file? You could send the ajax submission to it, then use Curl to submit the data to the actual form submission code get the response and convert it to html then return.

Comment: It didn't occur to me that a PHP request can only be made once. No wonder it's been so hard to find a solution.
Although I was thinking about creating an intermediate script to handle the new data to display.
Thanks for your help

Comment: PHP never gets sent to the client (as long as web server is setup correctly). It runs on the server and gets converted into simple text, normally delivered as HTML.

Comment: I know it does it just never occurred to me to think about this while I was trying to solve this and ended up on a wild goose chase and banging my head against a wall

Comment: Thank you none the less though